# Reload page when back from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page on which iframe is embedded which is hidden initially.

When clicking on the button, iframe gets opened. If clicked two times and then click browser back button it getting redirected to cached first iframe and not on the button page.

I am doing the following code to reload the page hence it go to the button page inside the document ready.

```
                window.history.pushState('', null, './');
                $(window).on('popstate', function() {

                    location.reload();
                });
```

Sometimes it doesn't work. Not sure where I am doing wrong.

Any recommendations, please.

Is there any way to prefetch iframe with different sessions?

Updating iframe src vs ajax call and then append data to iframe HTML, which is fast?

Comment: if you don't want the button to be clicked twice then why not hide the button once it has been used?

Comment: I was talking about the browser back button. It should apply on the page where iframe loaded.

Comment: Yes but you mentioned that the issue occurs as a result of this button being clicked twice. So why not simply prevent it from being clicked twice, then the problem cannot occur? That is likely to be a lot simpler than trying to figure the rest of it out.